# How to change the Backend IP after the Angular Frontent was built, and hosted with nginx?

Tags: angular, nginx, frontend, backend, ubuntu-18.04

For a project with a WebInterface we use an Intel NUC with Ubuntu 18.04. The backend is already running on the device and communicates with the frontend via a WebSocket. The front end is hosted with the WebSever software nginx and was built with Angular. Now when we building the frontend with "ng build --prod" the Ip address of the backend is baked in. The backend ip is set in environment.prod.ts before building.

How do you manage that when the forontend (with DNS or IP) is called, the current NUC address is used for communication with the backend?

The only way we see at the moment is to rebulid the Frontend if the ip chnages, thats bad.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a config file that you load at runtime, and in which you string replace the backend IP at deployment time.
See for instance this blogpost: https://christianlydemann.com/implementing-dynamic-environments-in-angular-for-avoiding-one-build-per-environment/

And/ or this NPM package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/runtime-config-loader